# $P(A|B) = P(A|B')$?

Tags: probability, independence

If two events $A$ and $B$ are independent, is it necessarily true that $P(A|B) = P(A|B')$?  If not, what is a counterexample?  I can't get the formula to fall out from any definition of independence, but am having a hard time proving it wrong.  Does it make a difference if $A$ and $B$ are both binary?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $P(B), P(B') >0$, so that the statements above make sense. Then you have $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A)$ by the definition of independence. If you know that independence of $A$ and $B$ guarantees independence of $A$ and $B'$, a similar thing shows that $P(A|B') = P(A).$

Or, $P(A\cap B') = P(A) - P(A\cap B)= P(A) - P(A)P(B)= P(A) (1-P(B))= P(A)P(B')$.

Comment: But that's the OP's question:  does independence wrt one necessarily imply independence wrt the complement?

Comment: Okay, I edited it.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense written out that way.

Comment: Then, since $P(A|B) = P(A)$ and $P(A) = P(A|B'), P(A|B)=P(A|B')$.  I see it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly. And no problem :)

Comment: This is much simpler, I have unnecessarily complicated it!

Answer (score 2):

Not a mathematical answer, but you can think of it this way:

*If A is independant of B, then Probability of A when B occurs must be equal to Probability of A when B does not occur.*

**Mathematical answer:**

$$\begin{align}P(A|B') &= \dfrac{P(A\cap B')}{P(B')} \\
&=  \dfrac{P(A) - P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}\end{align}$$

Simplify and solve by writing $P(B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$

$$P(A\cap B')\left(1-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\right)= P(B') (P(A) -P(A\cap B))$$

On rearranging you get:

$$\dfrac{P(A\cap B')}{P(B')} = P(A) =\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Comment: The non-mathematical answer makes sense, but the mathematical one I'm having trouble with.  Do you have an error in the second equality (numerator of the RHS)?  Should $P(A|B)$ fall from that?

Comment: How does the last bit give $P(A \mid B)$?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.  I don't see it.

Comment: Then you can use $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. Ill edit that in.

Comment: So then the RHS becomes $\frac{P(A) - P(A)P(B)}{1 - P(B)} = \frac{P(A)[1 - P(B)]}{1-P(B)} = P(A)$.  Then our equality falls out.  Thanks!